# Format NSTimeInterval as Minutes:Seconds:milliseconds

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimeinterval

Can anyone please tell me how to display milliseconds in this piece of code?

```
-(void)updateViewForPlayerInfo:(AVAudioPlayer*)p {
    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimeLeft)userInfo:p repeats:YES];
}

- (void)updateTimeLeft {
    NSTimeInterval timeLeft = player.duration - player.currentTime;

    int min=timeLeft / 60;
    int sec=lroundf(timeLeft) % 60;

    durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%02d:%02d",min,sec,nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0167 target:self selector:@selector(updateTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)updateTimer {
    countDownTotalTimer++;     
    TotalTime.text=[self timeFormatted:countDownTotalTimer];
}

- (NSString *)timeFormatted:(int)milli
{
    int millisec = ((milli) % 60)+39; 
    int sec = (milli / 60) % 60; 
    int min = milli / 3600; 

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d",min, sec, millisec]; 
}
```

If any wants milliseconds to max 60 than edit this line

```
int millisec = ((milli) % 60)+39;
```

**to**

```
int millisec = ((milli) % 60);
```

Comment: if any wants milliseconds to max 60 than edi this line              int millisec = ((milli) % 60)+39;   to                                 int millisec = ((milli) % 60);

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. Don't you just have to create a new variable for the milliseconds?

```
NSInteger milliseconds = (sec * 1000);

durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%02d:%02d.%04d",min,sec, milliseconds, nil];
```

Comment: This is what i did and it still counts in seconds..   eg- 02:05.05000, 02:06.0600...I'm missing something in my calculation that multiplies seconds....

Comment: oh right....my brain just started working again...05000 milliseconds is 5 seconds..!Pft!...Have you any idea how i can get this timer to display each millisecond and not in groups of 1000? eg- 02:05.1234, 02:05.1235...?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest solution:

```
durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%02d:%06.3f",
    (int)(timeLeft / 60), fmod(timeLeft, 60)];
```

That formats the time as `MM:SS.sss`. If you really want it as `MM:SS:sss` (which I don't recommend), you can do this:

```
durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%02d:%02d:%03.0f",
    (int)(timeLeft / 60), (int)fmod(timeLeft, 60), 1000*fmod(timeLeft, 1)];
```

Note that `stringWithFormat:` does not require `nil` at the end of its argument list.